# view details for exception in vs 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2017

I want to see details about the exception, e.g. call stack

there is no link in the dialog to see details, there is just copy details action

[image]

how can I activate it in VS2017?

[dialogs, what I looking for](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/31/using-the-new-exception-helper-in-visual-studio-15-preview/)

thanks for your help.

Comment: The debugging engine in VS2017 is not very good at providing details when the exception is raised very early.  Do the opposite of what the Microsoft employee told you to do, "use managed compatibility mode" forces an older debugging engine to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please disable "**Use Managed Compatibility Mode**" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General.

Debug it again.

Comment: @mojtaba357, Do you resolve this issue? Please feel free to share the latest information in your side?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the box for "just my code" in the debugger options to get the full info (and to suppress exceptions in 3rd party code unless they enter your code)